# Tree diagram in rdl ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008, rdl

I have a data set with following data :

[image]

How can I display this in tree view in rdl.  something like below or any form which can display in tree structure :

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to express this as a chart? I'm unsure of what you mean by "tree-view in RDL". The RDL itself is the report. You can display this exactly as you have in image 1 by using a Tablix and adding the data in the rows/columns, or, you can Insert ==>Chart==> Funnel to depict the hierarchy you want to show from top to bottom. 

Another way you could achieve this is to set your Grandparent as a parameter. That way when users choose a Grandparent, it will show all results under "1" or "2"

Comment: Hi Geo,  I wanted output on rdl report like the second figure. First figure is my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Along with my comment, this link might prove useful in depicting the hierarchy you want using charts. SSRS does not have explicit tree-diagrams that I am aware of, however, you can surely build custom bar charts with groupings to illustrate the above:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964128(v=sql.90).aspx